# Seg fault with multiprocessing.Array using ctypes.c_char_p

Tags: python, multiprocessing, segmentation-fault, ctypes

I wanted to create a multiprocessing.Array that stores byte strings of audio data and I read that the ctypes.c_char_p is the appropriate ctype to create such an Array, but when I tried to initialise the array with a small array of integers, this error was thrown:

```
>>> spam = multiprocessing.Array(ctypes.c_char_p, [1, 2, 3])
>>> spam[:]
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Is this a problem with the array I am using to initialise it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to create an *array* of pointers to byte strings so the second argument to the `multiprocessing.Array` initializer should be either the *integer* size of the array (i.e. the number of elements), or the correct type of initializer, which should be a list of byte strings in your case:

```py
import multiprocessing
import ctypes

# Create array of one pointer to a bytestring:
spam = multiprocessing.Array(ctypes.c_char_p, [b'abc'])
print(spam[0])
```

Prints:

```None
b'abc'
```

However, there is a problem: if you try to pass this `Array` instance to another process, will the character pointer contained within the array still be a valid address in the child process. In general, the answer is no. For platforms that use method *fork* to create new processes, that new child process will inherit its memory from the main process and you will probably be able to pass the array to the child and it will be able to access the byte string. But this will fail on platforms such as Windows that use method *spawn* to create new processes where the child process starts off with a new address space:

```py
def worker(arr):
    print(arr[0])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    from multiprocessing import Process, Array
    from ctypes import c_char_p

    spam = Array(c_char_p, [b'abc'])
    print(spam[0])
    p = Process(target=worker, args=(spam,))
    p.start()
    p.join()
```

However, there is no problem in passing an array of byte *characters* or *wide characters*. For example:

```py
def worker(arr):
    b = b''.join(arr)
    print(b)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    from multiprocessing import Process, Array
    from ctypes import c_char

    spam = Array(c_char, b'abc')
    p = Process(target=worker, args=(spam,))
    p.start()
    p.join()
```

Prints:

```None
b'abc'
```

**If you wanted to pass either a byte string or a *Unicode* character string, I would suggest you pass instead an array of bytes or characters.**